# Batch inference failed: prediction failure

Tags: python, amazon-sagemaker, large-language-model, falcon, pyprocessing

After executing the workshop code from the notebook below:

Deploy Falcon 7B instruct on Amazon SageMaker
https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/main/inference/generativeai/llm-workshop/deploy-falcon-40b-and-7b/falcon-7b-instruct-mpi.ipynb

I got an error like below after trying to perform queries using the created endpoint:
{"code":424,"message":"Batch inference failed","properties":{},"content":{"keys":[],"values":[]}}

Some logs I find in Cloudwatch are like below. Any ideas about what has happened ?

Edited 2023-10-09 (image upload didn´t work well). See below a Cloudwatch log:

```
| 1696286212592 | [WARN ] RollingBatch - Batch inference failed: prediction failure                                                                                                                   |                                     
| 1696286212592 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:    self._prefill_and_decode(preprocessed_new_requests)                                                                   |                                     
| 1696286212592 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:  File "/tmp/.djl.ai/python/0.23.0/djl_python/rolling_batch/scheduler_rolling_batch.py", line 131, in _prefill_and_decode |                                     
| 1696286212592 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:    self.scheduler.add_request(                                                                                           |                                     
| 1696286212592 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:  File "/tmp/.djl.ai/python/0.23.0/djl_python/scheduler/seq_batch_scheduler.py", line 114, in add_request                 |                                     
| 1696286212592 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:    self._add_request(input_ids[index_not_use_prompt],                                                                    |                                     
| 1696286212592 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:  File "/tmp/.djl.ai/python/0.23.0/djl_python/scheduler/seq_batch_scheduler.py", line 157, in _add_request                |                                     
| 1696286212592 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:    new_seq_batcher, output_ids = seq_batcher_cls.init_forward(                                                           |                                     
| 1696286212592 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/torch/utils/_contextlib.py", line 115, in decorate_context                 |                                     
| 1696286212592 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:    return func(*args, **kwargs)                                                                                          |                                     
| 1696286212592 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:  File "/tmp/.djl.ai/python/0.23.0/djl_python/scheduler/seq_batcher_impl.py", line 72, in init_forward                    |                                     
| 1696286212592 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:    lm_output = lm_block.forward(*model_input, past_key_values=kv_cache)                                                  |                                     
| 1696286212592 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:  File "/tmp/.djl.ai/python/0.23.0/djl_python/scheduler/lm_block.py", line 81, in forward                                 |                                     
| 1696286212592 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:    output = self.model.forward(input_ids=input_ids,                                                                      |                                     
| 1696286212592 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/accelerate/hooks.py", line 165, in new_forward                             |                                     
| 1696286212592 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:    output = old_forward(*args, **kwargs)                                                                                 |                                     
| 1696286212592 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:TypeError: forward() got an unexpected keyword argument 'position_ids'                                                    |                                     
| 1696286212592 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:Failed invoke service.invoke_handler()                                                                                    |                                     
| 1696286212592 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                        |                                     
| 1696286212592 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:  File "/tmp/.djl.ai/python/0.23.0/djl_python_engine.py", line 116, in run_server                                         |                                     
| 1696286212592 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:    outputs = self.service.invoke_handler(function_name, inputs)                                                          |                                     
| 1696286212592 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:  File "/tmp/.djl.ai/python/0.23.0/djl_python/service_loader.py", line 29, in invoke_handler                              |                                     
| 1696286212592 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:    return getattr(self.module, function_name)(inputs)                                                                    |                                     
| 1696286212592 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:  File "/tmp/.djl.ai/python/0.23.0/djl_python/huggingface.py", line 515, in handle                                        |                                     
| 1696286212592 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:    return _service.inference(inputs)                                                                                     |                                     
| 1696286212592 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:  File "/tmp/.djl.ai/python/0.23.0/djl_python/huggingface.py", line 275, in inference                                     |                                     
| 1696286212592 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:    outputs.add(result[idx], key="data", batch_index=i)                                                                   |                                     
| 1696286217531 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:IndexError: list index out of range                                                                                       |                                     
| 1696286230123 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:Rolling batch inference error                                                                                             |                                     
| 1696286230123 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                        |                                     
| 1696286230123 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:  File "/tmp/.djl.ai/python/0.23.0/djl_python/rolling_batch/rolling_batch.py", line 111, in try_catch_handling            |                                     
| 1696286230123 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:    return func(self, input_data, parameters)                                                                             |                                     
| 1696286230123 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:  File "/tmp/.djl.ai/python/0.23.0/djl_python/rolling_batch/scheduler_rolling_batch.py", line 55, in inference            |                                     
| 1696286230123 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:    self._prefill_and_decode(preprocessed_new_requests)                                                                   |                                     
| 1696286230123 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:  File "/tmp/.djl.ai/python/0.23.0/djl_python/rolling_batch/scheduler_rolling_batch.py", line 131, in _prefill_and_decode |                                     
| 1696286230123 | [WARN ] RollingBatch - Batch inference failed: prediction failure                                                                                                                   |                                     
| 1696286230123 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:    self.scheduler.add_request(                                                                                           |                                     
| 1696286230123 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:  File "/tmp/.djl.ai/python/0.23.0/djl_python/scheduler/seq_batch_scheduler.py", line 114, in add_request                 |                                     
| 1696286230123 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:    self._add_request(input_ids[index_not_use_prompt],                                                                    |                                     
| 1696286230123 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:  File "/tmp/.djl.ai/python/0.23.0/djl_python/scheduler/seq_batch_scheduler.py", line 157, in _add_request                |                                     
| 1696286230123 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:    new_seq_batcher, output_ids = seq_batcher_cls.init_forward(                                                           |                                     
| 1696286230123 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/torch/utils/_contextlib.py", line 115, in decorate_context                 |                                     
| 1696286230123 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:    return func(*args, **kwargs)                                                                                          |                                     
| 1696286230123 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:  File "/tmp/.djl.ai/python/0.23.0/djl_python/scheduler/seq_batcher_impl.py", line 72, in init_forward                    |                                     
| 1696286230123 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:    lm_output = lm_block.forward(*model_input, past_key_values=kv_cache)                                                  |                                     
| 1696286230123 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:  File "/tmp/.djl.ai/python/0.23.0/djl_python/scheduler/lm_block.py", line 81, in forward                                 |                                     
| 1696286230123 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:    output = self.model.forward(input_ids=input_ids,                                                                      |                                     
| 1696286230123 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/accelerate/hooks.py", line 165, in new_forward                             |                                     
| 1696286230123 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:    output = old_forward(*args, **kwargs)                                                                                 |                                     
| 1696286230123 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:TypeError: forward() got an unexpected keyword argument 'position_ids'                                                    |                                     
| 1696286230123 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:Failed invoke service.invoke_handler()                                                                                    |                                     
| 1696286230123 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                        |                                     
| 1696286230123 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:  File "/tmp/.djl.ai/python/0.23.0/djl_python_engine.py", line 116, in run_server                                         |                                     
| 1696286230123 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:    outputs = self.service.invoke_handler(function_name, inputs)                                                          |                                     
| 1696286230123 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:  File "/tmp/.djl.ai/python/0.23.0/djl_python/service_loader.py", line 29, in invoke_handler                              |                                     
| 1696286230123 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:    return getattr(self.module, function_name)(inputs)                                                                    |                                     
| 1696286230123 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:  File "/tmp/.djl.ai/python/0.23.0/djl_python/huggingface.py", line 515, in handle                                        |                                     
| 1696286230123 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:    return _service.inference(inputs)                                                                                     |                                     
| 1696286230123 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:  File "/tmp/.djl.ai/python/0.23.0/djl_python/huggingface.py", line 275, in inference                                     |                                     
| 1696286230123 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:    outputs.add(result[idx], key="data", batch_index=i)                                                                   |                                     
| 1696286234530 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:IndexError: list index out of range                                                                                       |                                     
| 1696286261435 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:Rolling batch inference error                                                                                             |                                     
| 1696286261435 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                        |                                     
| 1696286261435 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:  File "/tmp/.djl.ai/python/0.23.0/djl_python/rolling_batch/rolling_batch.py", line 111, in try_catch_handling            |                                     
| 1696286261435 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:    return func(self, input_data, parameters)                                                                             |                                     
| 1696286261435 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:  File "/tmp/.djl.ai/python/0.23.0/djl_python/rolling_batch/scheduler_rolling_batch.py", line 55, in inference            |                                     
| 1696286261435 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:    self._prefill_and_decode(preprocessed_new_requests)                                                                   |                                     
| 1696286261435 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:  File "/tmp/.djl.ai/python/0.23.0/djl_python/rolling_batch/scheduler_rolling_batch.py", line 131, in _prefill_and_decode |                                     
| 1696286261435 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:    self.scheduler.add_request(                                                                                           |                                     
| 1696286261435 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:  File "/tmp/.djl.ai/python/0.23.0/djl_python/scheduler/seq_batch_scheduler.py", line 114, in add_request                 |                                     
| 1696286261435 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:    self._add_request(input_ids[index_not_use_prompt],                                                                    |                                     
| 1696286261435 | [WARN ] RollingBatch - Batch inference failed: prediction failure                                                                                                                   |                                     
| 1696286261435 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:  File "/tmp/.djl.ai/python/0.23.0/djl_python/scheduler/seq_batch_scheduler.py", line 157, in _add_request                |                                     
| 1696286261435 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:    new_seq_batcher, output_ids = seq_batcher_cls.init_forward(                                                           |                                     
| 1696286261435 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/torch/utils/_contextlib.py", line 115, in decorate_context                 |                                     
| 1696286261435 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:    return func(*args, **kwargs)                                                                                          |                                     
| 1696286261435 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:  File "/tmp/.djl.ai/python/0.23.0/djl_python/scheduler/seq_batcher_impl.py", line 72, in init_forward                    |                                     
| 1696286261435 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:    lm_output = lm_block.forward(*model_input, past_key_values=kv_cache)                                                  |                                     
| 1696286261435 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:  File "/tmp/.djl.ai/python/0.23.0/djl_python/scheduler/lm_block.py", line 81, in forward                                 |                                     
| 1696286261435 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:    output = self.model.forward(input_ids=input_ids,                                                                      |                                     
| 1696286261435 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/accelerate/hooks.py", line 165, in new_forward                             |                                     
| 1696286261435 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:    output = old_forward(*args, **kwargs)                                                                                 |                                     
| 1696286261435 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:TypeError: forward() got an unexpected keyword argument 'position_ids'                                                    |                                     
| 1696286261435 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:Failed invoke service.invoke_handler()                                                                                    |                                     
| 1696286261435 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                        |                                     
| 1696286261435 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:  File "/tmp/.djl.ai/python/0.23.0/djl_python_engine.py", line 116, in run_server                                         |                                     
| 1696286261435 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:    outputs = self.service.invoke_handler(function_name, inputs)                                                          |                                     
| 1696286261435 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:  File "/tmp/.djl.ai/python/0.23.0/djl_python/service_loader.py", line 29, in invoke_handler                              |                                     
| 1696286261435 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:    return getattr(self.module, function_name)(inputs)                                                                    |                                     
| 1696286261435 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:  File "/tmp/.djl.ai/python/0.23.0/djl_python/huggingface.py", line 515, in handle                                        |                                     
| 1696286261435 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:    return _service.inference(inputs)                                                                                     |                                     
| 1696286261435 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:  File "/tmp/.djl.ai/python/0.23.0/djl_python/huggingface.py", line 275, in inference                                     |                                     
| 1696286261435 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:    outputs.add(result[idx], key="data", batch_index=i)                                                                   |                                     
| 1696286265530 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:IndexError: list index out of range                                                                                       |                                     
| 1696287848633 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:Rolling batch inference error                                                                                             |                                     
| 1696287848633 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                        |                                     
| 1696287848633 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:  File "/tmp/.djl.ai/python/0.23.0/djl_python/rolling_batch/rolling_batch.py", line 111, in try_catch_handling            |                                     
| 1696287848633 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:    return func(self, input_data, parameters)                                                                             |                                     
| 1696287848633 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:  File "/tmp/.djl.ai/python/0.23.0/djl_python/rolling_batch/scheduler_rolling_batch.py", line 55, in inference            |                                     
| 1696287848633 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:    self._prefill_and_decode(preprocessed_new_requests)                                                                   |                                     
| 1696287848633 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:  File "/tmp/.djl.ai/python/0.23.0/djl_python/rolling_batch/scheduler_rolling_batch.py", line 131, in _prefill_and_decode |                                     
| 1696287848633 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:    self.scheduler.add_request(                                                                                           |                                     
| 1696287848633 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:  File "/tmp/.djl.ai/python/0.23.0/djl_python/scheduler/seq_batch_scheduler.py", line 114, in add_request                 |                                     
| 1696287848633 | [WARN ] RollingBatch - Batch inference failed: prediction failure                                                                                                                   |                                     
| 1696287848633 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:    self._add_request(input_ids[index_not_use_prompt],                                                                    |                                     
| 1696287848633 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:  File "/tmp/.djl.ai/python/0.23.0/djl_python/scheduler/seq_batch_scheduler.py", line 157, in _add_request                |                                     
| 1696287848633 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:    new_seq_batcher, output_ids = seq_batcher_cls.init_forward(                                                           |                                     
| 1696287848633 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/torch/utils/_contextlib.py", line 115, in decorate_context                 |                                     
| 1696287848633 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:    return func(*args, **kwargs)                                                                                          |                                     
| 1696287848633 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:  File "/tmp/.djl.ai/python/0.23.0/djl_python/scheduler/seq_batcher_impl.py", line 72, in init_forward                    |                                     
| 1696287848633 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:    lm_output = lm_block.forward(*model_input, past_key_values=kv_cache)                                                  |                                     
| 1696287848633 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:  File "/tmp/.djl.ai/python/0.23.0/djl_python/scheduler/lm_block.py", line 81, in forward                                 |                                     
| 1696287848633 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:    output = self.model.forward(input_ids=input_ids,                                                                      |                                     
| 1696287848633 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/accelerate/hooks.py", line 165, in new_forward                             |                                     
| 1696287848633 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:    output = old_forward(*args, **kwargs)                                                                                 |                                     
| 1696287848633 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:TypeError: forward() got an unexpected keyword argument 'position_ids'                                                    |                                     
| 1696287848633 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:Failed invoke service.invoke_handler()                                                                                    |                                     
| 1696287848633 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                        |                                     
| 1696287848633 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:  File "/tmp/.djl.ai/python/0.23.0/djl_python_engine.py", line 116, in run_server                                         |                                     
| 1696287848633 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:    outputs = self.service.invoke_handler(function_name, inputs)                                                          |                                     
| 1696287848633 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:  File "/tmp/.djl.ai/python/0.23.0/djl_python/service_loader.py", line 29, in invoke_handler                              |                                     
| 1696287848633 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:    return getattr(self.module, function_name)(inputs)                                                                    |                                     
| 1696287848633 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:  File "/tmp/.djl.ai/python/0.23.0/djl_python/huggingface.py", line 515, in handle                                        |                                     
| 1696287848633 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:    return _service.inference(inputs)                                                                                     |                                     
| 1696287848633 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:  File "/tmp/.djl.ai/python/0.23.0/djl_python/huggingface.py", line 275, in inference                                     |                                     
| 1696287848633 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:    outputs.add(result[idx], key="data", batch_index=i)                                                                   |                                     
| 1696287853531 | [INFO ] PyProcess - W-88-falcon_src-stdout: [1,0]<stdout>:IndexError: list index out of range                                                                                       |                                     
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                     
                                        
[amazon-sagemaker]  [WARN ] RollingBatch - Batch inference failed: prediction failure  ("code":424,"message":"Batch inference failed")
```

I was expecting the result of the inference from the Falcon model for the proposed text (question).